# Bursting COGNOS reports include CC or BCC possible?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am currently bursting a Cognos 10 report with a list if dynamic email address and a unioned in static list.
The problem is all the recipients wind up in the "To" field.

Is there a way/trick to get the static (unchanging hard coded) email addresses into a bursted CC field as opposed to being in the "To" field in the outgoing outlook report?
I am not opposed to editing in XML if that is the only way to do it.
Thanks!